# Server.Mappath error

Tags: c#

iam trying to fill dropdown box feteching folder name from server but this code showing error.its working in local .but not working in server.can any one help on this

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~\\*.***.***.**\Flextronics\Common\Surendra"));
// DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\New Folder");
ddlModel.DataSource = dirInfo.GetDirectories();
ddlModel.DataBind();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "not working" means?

Comment: Don't put a ~ when trying to access a remote share and don't use Server.MapPath. Also, the user context that you are running under may not have permissions to the share on the remote server. Are you getting an ArgumentException, SecurityException, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

`Server.MapPath(@"~\\*.***.***.**\Flex...` return virtual path and it works for you on local because you have physical path `"D:\...."`

So you will have to use `Request.MapPath("~/.....");` because it Maps the specified virtual path to a physical path.

Comment: i think he only wanted to hide the server address

Answer (score 0):

the ~ symbol looks to the parent folder of your code file on your local machine

To access a UNC on a network drive, you need something similar to:

```
Server.MapPath("\\\\servername\\folder\\desiredfile.ext");
```

The "\\\\" escapes the characters and you need to do that to navigate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Directory does not like Server.MapPath. Hard code it in:

```
...new DirectoryInfo("stringUNCtoLoadFilesFrom");
```